# Image Link Not Working

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

In my webpage I have set up an image link/anchor using the following code:

```
<div class="bg_1">
        <div class="Absolute-Center">
            <span style="font-size: 50px; color: aqua">in short.</span><br />
            LIVE LIFE AT YOUR OWN PACE.<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <a href="#home1"><img src="images/scrolldown.png" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100vh; background-color: black;" >
        <a name="home1"></a>
    </div>
```

However when I run my page this image does not appear to be clickable, nor does it take you anywhere when you click. Any ideas? If it makes any difference the image I am using is mostly transparent.
**Edit:**
I have narrowed the problem down to being caused by z-index. The CSS code for "bg__1" is as follows:

```
.bg_1 {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(http://31.media.tumblr.com/2c3a72acc53b1a78ef3b6c4986604cd2/tumblr_ni0jt8sKlY1sr6759o1_500.gif);
}
```

Removing the z-index line fixes the problem however I need the z-index for my layout.

Comment: Html which you posted here is working just fine. What is your page layout, maybe some other element is covering the image? Did you disable `pointer-events` in css? Could you create jsfiddle or share url of page where it is not working correctly? It will be easier to help you if people can see page where it is not working.

Comment: I am using visual studio and creating a web application, however the class Absolute-Center does change that divs z-index to -1. Would that have anything to do with the image being covered? I can still see the image though.

Comment: Yes, z-index could cause your issue, if there is also some other element overlapping image. Even if other element is transparent or empty, it will still prevent click on your image. Open your web page in chrome, right-click on image and select "inspect element", in developer tools you will see exactly which element is overlapping the image and preventing clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my error. Image links become un-responsive if they are contained in a div or block that has a negative z-index. So instead of making it negative to render below default. Keep its container at default and raise the z-index of those you want it to render behind.

Answer (score 2):

It might had happen because of the body element covering your link. Just decrease z-index property of the body element.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the layout of the page it is difficult to find the fix.
However, you have few possibilities:

- Change your page layout
- Remove `z-index: -1` from css styles
- Find the element which is overlapping your image and add `pointer-events: none` to it's style. Then, click events will pass through to image.
- Change `z-index` of element which is overlapping the image, and give it lower z-index value